# How to respond when you hear multiple Azans(call to prayer)?

Tags: salat, masjid, adhan

Asalamualaikum,

I think many of you may have come across this issue. Generally when we hear the Azan , we do the following:

---

Repeat what the Mu'aththin says, except for when he says:

"حَيَّ عَلَى الصَّلاَةِ وَحَيَّ عَلَى الْفَلَاحِ"

Hayya 'alas-Salaah (hasten to the prayer) and Hayya 'alal-Falaah (hasten to salvation). Here you should say:

"لَا حَوْلَ وَلَا قُوَّةَ إِلَّا بِاللهِ"

Laa hawla wa laa quwwata 'illaa billaah.(There is no might and no power except by Allah.)

---

But these days, if you happen to live in a muslim populated area, you will find a lot of mosques near by. I start answering the first Azan, I hear. Very soon other mosques also starts their Azan and it becomes very difficult to hold on to the first Azan. The voices of the Azan-s are almost similar. I am not sure what to do in this situation.

Answer (score 4):

### All perfect praise be to Allah

Yes this is the general issue. And i had discussed it with many people and al of them had same solution.

Follow one azaan from start to end, answer that azaan and listen all other azaans with respect. This is the best way to deal with it.

In hadees it states:

> إن الدين يسر
>   religion is easy

Although in the first place situation should not be like this, but because of every school of thought try to have its separate masjid in each area, that's the reason of this situation.

**Now in your situation** that you can't recognize which azaan you were following, than i think best solution is to follow most similar azaan, it is best you can do. You can guess the most similar one by the words it is at, and by the voice of person calling etc. **Just try to follow one azaan, if you can't confirm which one you were following, than you should follow most similar one.**

### Allah knows best