# Do I need to respond to an azan I hear even after I have prayed the Fard Salaat?

Tags: fiqh, masjid, adhan

A few questions popped into my mind regarding the Azan

- <s>How to respond to multiple azans that are being recited simultaneously?</s>
- How to respond to multiple azans that are being recited one after the other?
- Do I need to respond to an azan I hear even after I have prayed the Fard Salaat for that azan at a different masjid?

I have found the answer to the first question below:
[How to respond when you hear multiple Azans(call to prayer)?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/32872/how-to-respond-when-you-hear-multiple-azanscall-to-prayer)

Can someone guide me on the other two situations?

Comment: To repeat the words of the azan like these: http://mizafirzana.blogspot.in/2013/07/how-to-answer-call-of-prayer-azan-athan.html

Comment: Have in mind that responding the adhan is sunnah, so you don't "have to" respond it, but you are highly recommended to do so.